# How to change the title background color of the dialog?

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout

How do I change title's background  in this dialog ["Lesson Editor"]?

As you can see,the theme of my application is dark and in the title's background in the main activities are dark as i want, but somehow the dialog isn't.
Help me please!!

Here is the screenshot of my dialog:

[image]

Comment: Set and opacity so that it is semi transparent, it will make it darker.

Comment: how to do this ? i am new to xml sorry

Comment: Add some code to duplicate the issue, and I will change it for you.

Comment: here is the code where the dialog created:   @AdamBuchananSmith                                          'final Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
        d.setTitle("Lesson Editor");
        d.setContentView(R.layout.customd_layout);'

Comment: tried to change and add in the xml file -> android:alpha="0.3". it didnt affected the title and its background at all. @AdamBuchananSmith

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently I used it for my implementation, so here is my code.

You can do that by creating a new style in the styles.xml file:

```
<style name="question_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/question_dialog_title</item>
</style>

<style name="question_dialog_title" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">#5cc5cc</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and then, when you create your Dialog object, you wanna use this constructor:

```
answeringDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.question_dialog);
```

the output is:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome :-). You can change the theme for the dialog as you wish.

Comment: I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` but `android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle` doesn't work. Any help?